# How do I put Emojis in a custom status in discordpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How do I put Emojis in a custom status in discordpy in this:

```
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(
        status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("Test")
    )
```

Comment: Do you mean unicode emojis?*

Comment: I mean those from discord itself you can click on your profile picture to create a custom status and there you can choose an emoji and I want that for the bot

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, discord.py doesn't support custom statuses yet, so there is no current way to do that. HOWEVER, like Lucas Sans S said, you can put unicode emojis in the status, like:

`await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("Test ")`

You can find a lot of unicode emojis on [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org)